# I am having trouble to solve the error "Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This is my gradle files. How can I resolve this build error?
I am trying to build this project following Udemy project and it causes build error.
I have no idea how to solve this problem.

If you need some info you need to know, I will post it here.

**build.gradle(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my app level gradle file.

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devtides.dogs"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding.enabled = true
}
def kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
def lifeCycleExtensionVersion = '1.1.1'
def supportVersion = '28.0.0'
def retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
def glideVersion = '4.9.0'
def rxJavaVersion = '2.1.1'
def roomVersion = '2.4.0-beta01'
def navVersion = '2.4.0-beta02'
def preferencesVersion = '1.1.1'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifeCycleExtensionVersion"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2"

    //Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navVersion"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navVersion"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxJavaVersion"

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportVersion"

    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:$preferencesVersion"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //material design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-beta01'
}
```

Comment: share app level gradle file

Comment: @YaqoobBhatti I post it right now.

Comment: don't post it in answer edit your question and post there

Comment: First you should `Clean Project` and then `Invalidate Caches and Restart`

Comment: I tried to post it to my question but it said "too many coding " so I post it to answer..

Comment: clean project and Invalidate cashes did not work for me..

Comment: I updated the question adding app level gradle file. Please let me know if you know anything to solve. Thank you.

Comment: Mention the full error.

Answer (score 0):

Update your **build.gradle(project)** accordingly below code is working for me:-

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
//        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}
ext {
    supportlibVer = '29.0.2'// not used
    daggerVer = '2.14.1'
    annotationVersion = "10.0-b28"
    retrofitVer = '2.9.0'
    okHttpVer = '4.2.0'
    roomVersion = "2.2.4"
    dynamicanimation_version = "1.0.0"
    exoplayer_version = "2.11.8"
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```